# Reciving Error BC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'description' of 'Public Sub New(description As String, quanity As Integer)'

Tags: asp.net, webforms, new-operator

This is my first time posting and i am really desperate. I have researched everywhere even my textbook to solve my issue and have came up empty after 20hrs(split between 3 days) of trying to fix this one error. Here is the exact text the code displays on a web page when trying to access one of my pages while debugging.

`
    Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30455: Argument not specified for parameter 'description' of 'Public Sub New(description As String, quanity As Integer)'.

Source Error:

```
Line 52:         <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()>  _
Line 53:         Public Sub New()
Line 54:             MyBase.New
Line 55:             Dim dependencies() As String
Line 56:             CType(Me,Global.FinalProject.WebForm3).AppRelativeVirtualPath =       "~/PlasticWorms.aspx"


Source File: C:\Users\christopher\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\myapp    \4b7a0ffe\8a9f18fa\App_Web_plasticworms.aspx.cdcab7d2.9_c0ynxq.0.vb    Line: 54
```

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009

---

Public Class Display

```
Dim _customerFirstName As String
Dim _customerLastName As String
Dim _customerAddress As String
Dim _description As String = ""
Dim intQuanity As Integer = 0
Dim decCustomerID As Decimal = 0D
Dim customerInfo(3) As String
Dim price As Decimal
Dim decTotal As Decimal
Dim _result As String
Dim form4 As WebForm4
Dim form3 As WebForm3
Dim sale As Sale

Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Sub prints()
    sale = New Sale(decTotal)
    form4 = New WebForm4(customerInfo(0), customerInfo(1), customerInfo(2), CDec(customerInfo(3)))
    form3 = New WebForm3(_description, intQuanity)
    For Each S As String In customerInfo
        _result = " , " & vbNewLine & S
    Next
    _result = " , " & vbNewLine & _description & " , " & vbNewLine & decTotal


    form4.Result(_result)

End Sub
```

End Class

---

Public Class SaveData

```
Dim _customerFirstName As String
Dim _customerLastName As String
Dim _customerAddress As String
Dim _description As String = ""
Dim intQuanity As Integer = 0
Dim decCustomerID As Decimal = 0D
Dim price As Decimal
Dim total As Decimal
Dim _result As String
Dim strFileLocation As String = "D:\Sales.txt"
Dim form4 As WebForm4
Dim form3 As WebForm3



Sub New()
    MyBase.New()
End Sub

Sub save()

    form4 = New WebForm4(_customerFirstName, _customerLastName, _customerAddress, decCustomerID)
    form3 = New WebForm3(_description, intQuanity)
    Try
        Dim objWriter As IO.StreamWriter = _
            IO.File.AppendText(strFileLocation)

        objWriter.Write("ID: " & decCustomerID & ",")
        objWriter.Write("Customer First Name: " & _customerFirstName & ",")
        objWriter.Write("Customer Last Name: " & _customerLastName & ",")
        objWriter.Write("address: " & _customerAddress & ",")
        objWriter.Write("Purchase Description: " & _description & ",")
        objWriter.Write("Total: " & total & ",")
        objWriter.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Log file could not be written. Please Check that you have an E:\ drive on you're computer.")

    End Try

    Try


    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try



End Sub
```

End Class

---

Public Class Sale

```
Dim _customerFirstName As String
Dim _customerLastName As String
Dim _customerAddress As String
Dim _description As String = ""
Dim intQuanity As Integer = 0
Dim decCustomerID As Decimal = 0D
Dim price As Decimal
Dim decTotal As Decimal
Dim _result As String



Sub New(ByVal total As Decimal)

    total = decTotal
End Sub

Sub Calculate()

    price = 3.99D
    decTotal = intQuanity * price


End Sub
```

End Class

---

Public Class WebForm4
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim _customerFirstName As String
Dim _customerLastName As String
Dim _customerAddress As String
Dim _description As String = ""
Dim intQuanity As Integer = 0
Dim decCustomerID As Decimal = 0D
Dim price As Decimal
Dim decTotal As Decimal
Dim _result As String
Dim sale As Sale
Dim display As New Display
Dim saveData As New SaveData




Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub



Protected Sub btnPlaceOrder_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlaceOrder.Click
    sale = New Sale(decTotal)
    _customerFirstName = txtFirstName.Text
    _customerLastName = txtLastName.Text
    _customerAddress = txtAddress.Text
    sale.Calculate()
    saveData.save()
    display.prints()
    VBMath.Randomize(decCustomerID)

End Sub

Sub New(ByVal customerFirstName As String, ByVal customerLastName As String, ByVal customerAddress As String, ByVal customerID As Decimal)
    MyBase.New()
    customerID = decCustomerID
    customerFirstName = _customerFirstName
    customerLastName = _customerLastName
    customerAddress = _customerAddress
End Sub



Sub Result(ByVal result As String)
    lblResult.Text = result
    Calendar1.SelectedDate.Day.Equals(Calendar1.TodaysDate.AddDays(3))

End Sub
```

End Class

---

Public Class WebForm3
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim _description As String = ""
Dim intQuanity As Integer = 0


Sub New(ByVal description As String, ByVal quanity As Integer)
    MyBase.New()
    description = _description
    quanity = intQuanity

End Sub


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Protected Sub btnCheckOut_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckout.Click



    If chkBlue.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkBlue.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtBlueQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkBrown.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkBrown.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtBrownQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkCrawDad.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkCrawDad.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtCrawdadQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkMud.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkMud.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtMudQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkPurple.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkPurple.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtPurpleQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkPurpleSpeckled.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkPurpleSpeckled.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtPurpleSpeckledQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkRedDeath.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkRedDeath.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtRedDeathQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkSpeckledGray.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkSpeckledGray.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtSpeckledGrayQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkTan.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkTan.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtTanQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkWatermellon.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & chkWatermellon.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtWatermellonQty.Text)
    ElseIf chkYellowGreen.Checked = True Then
        _description += " , " & txtYellowGreenQty.Text
        intQuanity += CInt(txtYellowGreenQty.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("ERROR")

    End If


    Server.Transfer("OrderRecipt.aspx")



End Sub
```

End Class
`

Comment: My guess is that your class inherits from yet another class (which you haven't shown) that defines the two parameter constructor. Then, in the inherited class you try to call the no-parameter constructor of the base class but there is just no such constructor in the base class.

Comment: What have you already done to try and fix the error or reduce the possible problem source down to a much smaller part of your program?  My suggestion would be to begin commenting out parts of your code until you get down to something that works and then examining (and, if necessary, posting here) why that last thing you removed caused your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I thought the same thing Wiktor. I figure that the constructor in the base class was the problem. WebForm4 base class ends up being the System.Web.UI.Page class and this class does not have the constructor that matches for the program to run correctly. I think this is the problem but have no idea on how to modify a system class. I have reduced the program down to just putting all of m,y code in one class and the site runs fine. I can tell you that every page works but the WebForm3 aka the one in the error which is PlasticWorms.aspx . I hope this information helps

Comment: These error codes should point to the line in the class where the error is instead of what its showing because I have no sub new constructor in any class at line 53. I have re-wrote the code several times and it looks fine. I have no clue how to make this compiler stop showing the same error over and over.